# How to hide my css loader export, and other text in webpack error messages?

Tags: webpack, webpack-loader

I'm having a hard time troubleshooting my code, when webpack errors throw a wall of text.

For example: [image]

I found similar questions on SO (relating to making output less verbose), but they're either applicable to an older webpack version, or they don't work for other reasons, for example using the stats flag (stats: "minimal") or others found on https://webpack.js.org/configuration/stats/ ) still displays my css loader export and whatever else.

Here's my config. I'm sure I messed up something there, but not sure what...

```
    const path = require('path')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')

module.exports = {
  mode: "development", // production
  entry: {
    'main': './src/js/main.js',
    'lp-tidy-gsap': './src/js/lp-tidy-gsap.js'
  },
  watch: true,
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets'),
    filename: 'js/[name].bundled.js'
  },

  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '../style.css',
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: What output of the output do you want to hide exactly? Or do you just need help troubleshooting your problem?

Comment: I want to hide my css loader export, and other text in webpack error messages. I do not need help troubleshooting.

Comment: but your css loader has some errors if I see that correctly? Wouldn't it make more sense to resolve these errors?

Comment: No, that error has long been resolved. My issue isn't the error, but the annoying wall of text that I have to scroll to get to the source map of the error. 

Unrelated, and more important, my images referenced in my JS are being hashed and outputted in to my JS. Any way I can force webpack to not do that? (I updated my config in Q'n)